# Is there any faster way to solve this problem in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to create a simple application, but I have got the following message when I run the application:

> conversion from string to type double is not valid.

[image]

Comment: Please read this: [Ask]

Comment: Don't post pictures of code. Post code as text and formatted as code. If you are going to post a screenshot, don't arbitrarily shoot your entire screen. Shot only the part that is relevant.

Comment: I'm so sorry for any inconvenience may cause. But It is my first time here @jmcilhinney

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Integer values, try something like this:

```
Private Sub Textbox9_TextChanged(Textbox9Text As String, Textbox10Text As String)

    Dim tb9Val, tb10val As Integer
    If Not Integer.TryParse(Textbox9Text, tb9Val) OrElse Not Integer.TryParse(Textbox10Text, tb10val) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Textbox must contain Integer value", "Invalid Value")
    Else
        If tb9Val < 25 Then
            'Set Colour Red
        Else
            'set Colour other
        End If
        'etc
    End If

End Sub
```

As you only posted a photo of your code, I'm not going to retype it all.